# How to arrange sequence of numbers into subcategories to equal 21

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory, card-games

I have a bit of a brainteaser for a game my brother and I are playing ([link for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cV1VV_ycDdw)). The objective of the game is to arrange cards into categories where the sum equals 21. The game has four columns and you must arrange the cards into piles in the order they appear. Once a pile equals 21, the column restarts and the player is able to begin a new pile in that column. There is an exception to the sum equalling 21 where the player can make a pile of five cards where the sum is less than 21 and this restarts the pile as well. The player gets more points when they make piles equal 21 in succession to the last (ex. 4 piles each adding up to 11 and placing a face card on each pile to equal 21). The player can not go over 21. Wild cards can make any pile equal 21 (ex. a two tens and a Wild card equals 21). Face Cards = 10. W = wild card. A = 1 or 11. I am trying to make a perfect game with the following set of numbers: K, K, K, 2, 2, A, 7, Q, 5, 10, 6, 5, 2, 4, A, J, 4, 5, Q, 5, 3, Q, 10, K, W, 9, 6, Q, 10, W, 7, 6, 8, 10, 3, 8, A, A, 4, 9, J, 8, 6, 9, 2, 8, 4, 9, 3, 7, 7, 3.

Comment: You should clarify how much points is a '21' compared to a '5 cards less than 21', and how much are 'streaks'. (I know it is shown in the linked video, but the post should be self-contained.)